# c++ variable does not name a type in macro

Tags: c++, macros

Have this code:

```
#include <iostream>

int a=0;

#define F(f) \
  int t##f(int, int);\
  a ++;\
  int t##f(int i, int j)  

F(nn) {
    return i*j;
}

int main() {
 int b = tnn(3, 8);
 std::cout << a << b;
}
```

Got error when compiling:

```
7:3: error: 'a' does not name a type
10:1: note: in expansion of macro 'F'
```

Why isn't `a` visible in macro at the position it expands?

Comment: when I remove line `a++;\\`, everything goes all right, it prints 024.

Comment: It appears outside any valid scope for expression statements. I'd recommend to preprocess your code with `-E` and see what's the actual result.

Comment: You can use a `static` variable in a function if you want to keep incrementing `a`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your macro ( in the nn case) expands to:

```
int a=0;

int tnn(int, int); a ++; int tnn(int i, int j)  {
    return i*j;
}

int main() {
 int b = tnn(3, 8);
 std::cout << a << b;
}
```

There is no *global scope* in C++. That is only in scripting languages.
Execution order is an initialization library-- something like crt0.s which 
constructs your run time envioronment. Then initialize global variables ( this part can get very complicated ) then run main.

You statement fails simply because you cannot put arbitrariy executable code where the macro is expanded.

PS: Bjarne says don't use macros. In fact he create const, inline and to some degree templates so that you can avoid macros. **Macros are evil!!!!**

Comment: Nice answr -- you're more thorough than I was

Answer (score 7):

Look at the expansion of the macro:

`F(nn)` becomes

```
int tnn(int, int);
a++;
int tnn(int i, int j) {
  return i * j;
}
```

The variable 'a' is being incremented ***outside*** a function which is a syntax error.

Like the other answer said, you cannot execute statements wherever you please; statements must be inside a function in order to be valid.

There are a few things that can go in the *global scope*:

1. Namespace declaration and definitions
2. Global variable **declarations**
3. Function prototypes and definitions
4. Template and class declarations and definitions
5. Preprocessor directives

Things that must be in function scope:

1. Control statements such as if and for
2. Labels
3. Function **calls**

Finally, the above lists are not all inclusive.

Comment: OK, that's the difference between C++ and a script lang. Expression must be inside a function. Thx.